# JMS Serializer visitor continue default deserialization

Tags: jmsserializerbundle

I have configured a visitor for JMS Serialization:

```
class MyHandler implements SubscribingHandlerInterface
{

public static function getSubscribingMethods()
{
    return array(
        array(
            'direction' => GraphNavigator::DIRECTION_SERIALIZATION,
            'format' => 'json',
            'type' => 'MyObject',
            'method' => 'serializeContextParent',
        ),
    );
}

public function serializeContextParent(JsonSerializationVisitor $visitor, $data, array $type, Context $context)
{
    if (in_array('id', $type['params']))
        return $data->getId();

    // Do default deserialization ???
}

}
```

I would like to only deserialize the id of MyObject when there is a parameter id (so the type declared is @JMS\Type("MyObject<'id'>").

That works fine, however, if the parameter is not found, I want to continue the default deserialization.

Is that possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: Nope, what I did is use the exclusion policy, in my case, I excluded the parent (object), and added a method with VirtualProperty and SerializeName = 'id'.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a different Object type for the special case:

```
class MyObject {
    /**
     * @var User
     * @JMS\Type("User")
     * /
    protected $user;
    /**
     * @var User
     * @JMS\Type("UserWithId")
     * /
    protected $userWithId;
}
```

And the handler can be something as:

```
class MyHandler implements SubscribingHandlerInterface
{

public static function getSubscribingMethods()
{
    return array(
        array(
            'direction' => GraphNavigator::DIRECTION_SERIALIZATION,
            'format' => 'json',
            'type' => 'UserWithId',
            'method' => 'serializeContextParent',
        ),
    );
}

public function serializeContextParent(JsonSerializationVisitor $visitor, $data, array $type, Context $context)
{
    return $data->getId();
}

}
```

Since you know if the user has the id or not (you were using a  type parameter), you can instead use just a custom type name.

...and since is possible to add custom handlers on custom type, the solution should work